# Keras: list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have implemented a Keras model using the functional API:

```
x_inp, x_out = graphsage_model.in_out_tensors()
prediction = layers.Dense(units=train_targets.shape[1], activation="softmax")(x_out)
model = Model(inputs=x_inp, outputs=prediction)
model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.005),
    loss=losses.categorical_crossentropy,
    metrics=["acc"],
)
```

With tensors are:

```
x_inp:  [<tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(None, 1, 1433) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'input_2:0' shape=(None, 10, 1433) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'input_3:0' shape=(None, 50, 1433) dtype=float32>]
x_out:  Tensor("lambda/Identity:0", shape=(None, 32), dtype=float32)
prediction:  Tensor("dense/Identity:0", shape=(None, 7), dtype=float32)
train_targets.shape[1] = 7
```

As far as I understand is that my model has 50 units in the input layer, 32 in the hidden layer and 7 in the output layer in the functional API approach. To understand how the Sequential model of Keras works in contrast with the functional API, I've tried to implement this in the Sequential approach:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='softmax', input_shape=(50,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
```

But it gives me the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays
>   that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
>   Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 3
>   arrays:

Additional info about how the x_inp and x_out were computed:

```
def in_out_tensors(self, multiplicity=None):
    """
    Builds a GraphSAGE model for node or link/node pair prediction, depending on the generator used to construct
    the model (whether it is a node or link/node pair generator).

    Returns:
        tuple: (x_inp, x_out), where ``x_inp`` is a list of Keras input tensors
        for the specified GraphSAGE model (either node or link/node pair model) and ``x_out`` contains
        model output tensor(s) of shape (batch_size, layer_sizes[-1])

    """
    if multiplicity is None:
        multiplicity = self.multiplicity

    if multiplicity == 1:
        return self._node_model()
    elif multiplicity == 2:
        return self._link_model()
    else:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "Currently only multiplicities of 1 and 2 are supported. Consider using node_model or "
            "link_model method explicitly to build node or link prediction model, respectively."
        )

def _node_model(self):
    """
    Builds a GraphSAGE model for node prediction

    Returns:
        tuple: (x_inp, x_out) where ``x_inp`` is a list of Keras input tensors
        for the specified GraphSAGE model and ``x_out`` is the Keras tensor
        for the GraphSAGE model output.

    """
    # Create tensor inputs for neighbourhood sampling
    x_inp = [
        Input(shape=(s, self.input_feature_size)) for s in self.neighbourhood_sizes
    ]

    # Output from GraphSAGE model
    x_out = self(x_inp)

    # Returns inputs and outputs
    return x_inp, x_out
```

Comment: Can you please print train_targets.shape? Also, x_inp is a list of 3 arrays is that what you expected?

Comment: train_targets.shape[1] = 7. I've added to the post. No I don't get why I have a list of 3 arrays of three axes in x_inp.

Comment: It gives the error because in the Sequential model your input is just 1 array and in the functional API you pass input=x_inp and x_inp is a list of 3 arrays thus giving the following error. If you could explain a little bit more what is x_inp and x_out maybe I could help you more, but only this information I really don't know.

Comment: @BrunoMello I've added the functions how x_inp and x_out are computed. What does this list of 3 array shapes mean? how can I transform it to 1 array?

Comment: "where ``x_inp`` is a list of Keras input tensors", it already says in the docstring that x_inp is a list. I would suggest using the functional API as you have done it in the first case, as far as I know, it is not possible to use the sequential model with lists